# tabindex issue with select2

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery-select2

I am having an issue with the taborder on my form whilst using select2.

I have an input form that I want the user to be able to tab through in order.

I have been able to order the text input fields but not select2 dropdownlists.

It appears the issue is with them having a default tabindex="-1", as below;

```
>  <div id="s2id_ctl00_MainContent_ddlAreaKept" class="select2-container
> form-control">
>     <a class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1" onclick="return false;" href="javascript:void(0)">
>     <input id="s2id_autogen4" class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text" tabindex="0">
>     <div class="select2-drop select2-display-none select2-with-searchbox">
>     </div>
>     <select id="ctl00_MainContent_ddlAreaKept" class="form-control select2-offscreen" name="ctl00$MainContent$ddlAreaKept" tabindex="-1">
```

I have also written the following javascript to add tabIndex values to the fields but it isn't working how I'd like.

```
   var tabOrder = 0;

document.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_ddlAreaKept").tabIndex = tabOrder++;
document.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_ddlNCDYears").tabIndex = tabOrder++;
document.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_txtVehicleValue").tabIndex = tabOrder++;
document.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_txtAge").tabIndex = tabOrder++;
document.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_txtForename").tabIndex = tabOrder++;
document.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_txtSurname").tabIndex = tabOrder++;
document.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_txtEmail").tabIndex = tabOrder++;
document.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_txtPhoneNumber").tabIndex = tabOrder++;
document.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_btnGetQuote").tabIndex = tabOrder++;
```

The dropdownlists don't get tabbed into, it skips them and goes through the textboxes as it should.

Any help much appreciated!

SOLVED : I tried:

```
var tabOrder = 1;
```

and this has solved the issue.  I don't exactly know why or how :|

Comment: this actually happens to me on django select2 plugin

Answer (score 3):

There is a solution in github, you can create a js file and then you include it under the call of select2, inside this new file you must paste this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var docBody = $(document.body);
    var shiftPressed = false;
    var clickedOutside = false;
    //var keyPressed = 0;

    docBody.on('keydown', function(e) {
        var keyCaptured = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        //shiftPressed = keyCaptured == 16 ? true : false;
        if (keyCaptured == 16) { shiftPressed = true; }
    });
    docBody.on('keyup', function(e) {
        var keyCaptured = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        //shiftPressed = keyCaptured == 16 ? true : false;
        if (keyCaptured == 16) { shiftPressed = false; }
    });

    docBody.on('mousedown', function(e){
        // remove other focused references
        clickedOutside = false;
        // record focus
        if ($(e.target).is('[class*="select2"]')!=true) {
            clickedOutside = true;
        }
    });

    docBody.on('select2:opening', function(e) {
        // this element has focus, remove other flags
        clickedOutside = false;
        // flag this Select2 as open
        $(e.target).attr('data-s2open', 1);
    });
    docBody.on('select2:closing', function(e) {
        // remove flag as Select2 is now closed
        $(e.target).removeAttr('data-s2open');
    });

    docBody.on('select2:close', function(e) {
        var elSelect = $(e.target);
        elSelect.removeAttr('data-s2open');
        var currentForm = elSelect.closest('form');
        var othersOpen = currentForm.has('[data-s2open]').length;
        if (othersOpen == 0 && clickedOutside==false) {
            /* Find all inputs on the current form that would normally not be focus`able:
             *  - includes hidden <select> elements whose parents are visible (Select2)
             *  - EXCLUDES hidden <input>, hidden <button>, and hidden <textarea> elements
             *  - EXCLUDES disabled inputs
             *  - EXCLUDES read-only inputs
             */
            var inputs = currentForm.find(':input:enabled:not([readonly], input:hidden, button:hidden, textarea:hidden)')
                .not(function () {   // do not include inputs with hidden parents
                    return $(this).parent().is(':hidden');
                });
            var elFocus = null;
            $.each(inputs, function (index) {
                var elInput = $(this);
                if (elInput.attr('id') == elSelect.attr('id')) {
                    if ( shiftPressed) { // Shift+Tab
                        elFocus = inputs.eq(index - 1);
                    } else {
                        elFocus = inputs.eq(index + 1);
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            if (elFocus !== null) {
                // automatically move focus to the next field on the form
                var isSelect2 = elFocus.siblings('.select2').length > 0;
                if (isSelect2) {
                    elFocus.select2('open');
                } else {
                    elFocus.focus();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    docBody.on('focus', '.select2', function(e) {
        var elSelect = $(this).siblings('select');
        if (elSelect.is('[disabled]')==false && elSelect.is('[data-s2open]')==false
            && $(this).has('.select2-selection--single').length>0) {
            elSelect.attr('data-s2open', 1);
            elSelect.select2('open');
        }
    });

});
```

This work for me, if you want to know more: https://github.com/peledies/select2-tab-fix

© 2017 GitHub, Inc.
Terms
Privacy
Security
Status
Help
Contact GitHub
API
Training
Shop
Blog
About

Answer (score 3):

focus it after select it!

```
$('.select2').on('select2:select', function (e) {
$(this).focus();
});
```

for your code replace .select2-offscreen with  my .select2.

S F My English!

Answer (score 0):

You could bind load event and trigger it on first time loaded

As you can see , the tabindex of the select control will become "3" instead of "-1"

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var $select2 = $("#tab2");
    $select2.data('placeholder', 'Please Chhose').select2({
                  formatNoMatches: function (term) {
                        return 'No Match "' + term + '" Item';
                    },
                    allowClear: true
 }).on("load", function(e) { 
     $(this).prop('tabindex',3);
 }).trigger('load');


  $("#tab1").prop('tabindex',4);
  $("#tab3").prop('tabindex',2);
  $("#tab4").prop('tabindex',1);

}
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/wicutoti/24/edit)

Comment: Thanks! But I managed to sort the issue by simply starting my 'var tabOrder = 1'.  This has solved the issue but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me. I focus the first element in the modal:

```
$('#modalId').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
     $('#FirstElement').focus()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

TabIndex Issue might happens after the form reset.
As per the [documentation](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items) You may clear all current selections in a Select2 control by setting the value of the control to null:

```js
$(selector).val(null).trigger("change");
```